# Show/Hide within jQuery File Upload Plugin

Tags: show-hide, jquery-file-upload

I am using PHP with the "jQuery File Upload Plugin" by Sebastian Tschan (https://blueimp.net) and within the upload and download templates I want to do some simple show/hide stuff but can't figure out how to do it.

When you first view the page I only want to be able to see the "Add files..." button.

Then when files are added (by whichever method) the "Start upload" should then appear along with the "Cancel" button.

Once uploaded I then want a block of text to say something like "You have successfully uploaded [X] photographs. These will now be reviewed by our assessors. Your reference for these uploaded images is [XXXXXXXXX].". This block of text will appear once directly below the last uploaded image in the Download template.

Obviously the upload is using JQuery/JavaScript and not PHP and I am trying to look for some sort of trigger to detect how many images are being uploaded and when that upload is complete.

I also want to disable the "Start upload" button once it has been triggered so as to prevent uploading files twice.

Regards, Neil

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
            {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" style="display:none;">
                    <!--<i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>-->`enter code here`
                    <!--<span>Start</span>-->
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to use the event described in the documentation ?